# MVC 4 Export to Excel Failing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, export-to-excel, contenttype

I have the following code in a controller in and MVC 4 application

```
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=export.xml");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-type", "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

    var rows = data.Split('\n');
    var sheet = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" + Environment.NewLine;
    sheet += "<?mso-application progid=\"Excel.Sheet\"?>" + Environment.NewLine;

    sheet += "<ss:Workbook xmlns:ss=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\" xmlns:html=\"http://www.w3.org/tr/rec-html40\">" + Environment.NewLine;
    sheet += "<ss:Worksheet ss:Name=\"Sheet1\">" + Environment.NewLine;
    sheet += "<ss:Table>" + Environment.NewLine;

    foreach (var r in rows)
    {
        sheet += "<ss:Row>" + Environment.NewLine;

        var columns = r.Split(',');

        foreach (var column in columns)
        {
            sheet += "<ss:Cell>" + Environment.NewLine;
            sheet += "<ss:Data ss:Type=\"String\">" + column + "</ss:Data>" + Environment.NewLine;
            sheet += "</ss:Cell>" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        sheet += "</ss:Row>" + Environment.NewLine;
    }
    sheet += "</ss:Table>" + Environment.NewLine;
    sheet += "</ss:Worksheet>" + Environment.NewLine;
    sheet += "</ss:Workbook>" + Environment.NewLine;

    return Content(sheet);
```

If I put a breakpoint and copy the value of the sheet variable into notepad and save that locally on my machine as export.xml I can then open that file up fine and it has no issues.

The problem I have is that when I let this method in the controller continue running I get a prompt back in the browser to open an file, which is what I would expect, but when I click open, excel opens and then I get and error message.  The error message that I get is

Microsoft Excel cannot open or save any more documents because there is not enough available memory or disk space.

What am I missing to make this controller pass in the correct information back to the browser.

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/officesetupdeployprevious/thread/2c753037-4600-4a4f-abd7-d228e2f20a38/ try this

Comment: That link doesn't help, it is not really the same thing.